# Playback of downloaded (not streamed) video

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to download, save, and playback video files from a server. My download and save technic seems to be working but I cannot playback the video. The video's path on the server is correct, and this technic also works fine for downloading, saving and viewing pngs. Also, the MPMoviePlayerController seems to find the file, it just can't play it. I get a black area where the video should be.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code (target: iOS 6.1, xCode 5).

```
//Downloading & Saving
-(void)downloadFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    NSURL *url                  = [NSURL URLWithString:path];     
     NSMutableURLRequest *req    = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    //NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:pathForCurrentFile contents:nil attributes:nil];
    currentFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:pathForCurrentFile];
    if (currentFile)
    {
    [currentFile seekToEndOfFile];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    //NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if( currentFile != nil){
        if (currentFile)  {
            [currentFile seekToEndOfFile];
        }
        [currentFile writeData:data];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s, %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [currentFile closeFile];
}
```

Below is the code for playback

```
    //Playback
    NSString *loopFilePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path stringByAppendingPathComponent:vidFileName];

    NSURL *vidURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:vidFilePath];

    self.vidController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:vidURL];
    self.vidController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480);
    self.vidController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [self.view addSubview:self.vidController.view];
    [self.vidController prepareToPlay];
    [self.vidController play];
```

Comment: For the love of FSM, "technique".

Comment: What type of file is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.loopVidController.view];
```

should be this:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.vidController.view];
```

Try this:

```
self.vidController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:vidURL];
self.vidController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
self.vidController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.vidController.view];
[self.vidController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but that was just a typo from me copying the code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: When saving and playing back the video file you must append the file extension. In this case .mov. When using this same technique for .png files, the extension isn't necessary.